# Python annotation for type with writeable attribute

Tags: python, annotations, python-typing

I have a function that sticks an attribute called `.addr` onto objects, something like this (simplified):

```
def add_addr(x: Any, stuff):
    object.__setattr__(x, 'addr', make_addr_from(stuff))
```

(Yes, this even modifies immutable objects.)

This means that `x` must not be a primitive type such as `int` or `str`. Therefore `Any` is not a suitable type annotation for `x`. What would be a suitable type annotation for `x`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect the annotation for ``x`` to convey? "Has a writeable ``x`` attribute?" Note that there are more types than primitives that cannot be modified this way – for example, types with ``__slots__`` won't allow setting new attributes either.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes: `x` is "any object that we can arbitrarily give a `.addr` attribute, whether it has one already or not". I expect `x` most likely to be a dataclass object (the need for this arises from difficulties with dataclass constructors and hashing), but not necessarily. Good point about `__slots__`: the annotation must also disallow those. That belongs in an answer. :)

Comment: I don't think such an annotation exists. One can annotate "has attribute ``.addr``" and "has a readable/writeable attribute ``.addr``" but not "can create an attribute ``.addr``". If you want to do this only on specific types of objects (the dataclass objects you alude to) my hunch is that you should annotate it as such – but it might also just be an XY problem due to "difficulties with ... constructors and hashing".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That sounds like it could be an answer. My problem might be an XY problem, but I think that would require a separate question. This problem is, "_If_ I want to arbitrarily tag objects with an _.addr_ attribute, how would I make a type annotation to allow only objects where that is possible?" Knowing the answer, even if it's "it can't be done", will help me choose a good way way to solve original problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works with primitive types, too, but you have to create a derived class, because the built-in classes have a limited set of attributes. This applies to structured types like list, tuple and dict, too.

```
class MyInt (int):
    pass

i = MyInt(42)
add_addr(i, whatever)
```

As far as the annotation is concerned, I think it would make sense to create an abstract class that is used as a base for objects that allow setting an attribute with `add_addr`, and use that base class for the annotation.

I’m afraid there is no other way to distinguish between built-in classes and derived classes for the purpose of type annotations.

Alternatively, keep the `Any` annotation, and inside the function use a `try...except AttributeError` clause.

Comment: What should the type annotation be, to specify that a type like `MyInt` should be passed to `add_addr` rather than a type like `int`?

Comment: I haven’t tried this myself, but you should be able to create an abstract base class `attr_settable` (without any methods or variables), and make `MyInt` inherit from that base class. Note that Python supports multiple inheritance, so `MyInt` can have both `int` and `attr_settable` as parents. Then use `attr_settable` for the type annotation.

Comment: Would this require that I make every class ever passed to `add_addr` inherit from the abstract class? That might be difficult.

Comment: Yes, that would be an requirement. I’m sorry, but I can’t think of a better solution. Maybe someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Alternatively, keep the `Any` annotation, and inside the function use a `try...except AttributeError` clause. This will only catch errors at run time, though. You cannot do static type checking this way, I’m afraid, if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! `try...except` might be the best workaround. Let's see if anyone else can come up with something; if not, then if you edit your answer to say "It can't be done, so you have to settle for try...except", I'll accept that.

Comment: Ok, I have extended the answer to mention the `try...except` alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The Python `typing` system has no way to annotate "any object on which `.addr` is writeable". Either annotate `x` with some specific objects known to be compatible, or use a `Protocol` for a read/write `.addr`.

---

If the function is intended only for some specific objects that knowingly work with it, annotate it as such:

```py
from typing import Any

class Foo:
    """Type with writeable `__dict__`"""
    pass

def add_addr(x: Foo, stuff: Any):
    object.__setattr__(x, 'addr', stuff)

add_addr(Foo(), 2)
```

In this case, MyPy is trusting you that `Foo` works with the function. This does not say anything about other types that might-or-might-not work with the function.

---

If the function is intended for any objects that are *provably compatible*, define a `Protocol` for the require features:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol

class RWAddr(Protocol):
    """The structural type of 'asnything with read/write `.addr`'"""
    addr: Any  # note: could also use a property/setter pair

class Bar:
    """Type with writeable `.addr` and other stuff"""
    addr: Any
    port: int


def add_addr(x: RWAddr, stuff: Any):
    object.__setattr__(x, 'addr', stuff)

add_addr(Bar(), 2)
```

In this case, MyPy will *verify* that the arguments satisfies the protocol. This means that MyPy must *actively know* that a type has a writeable `.addr` – for example, the previous `Foo` does not satisfy this.